# JQ filtering and map basic: removing null values and transforming text to lowercase

Tags: json, bash, unix, jq

Sample input:

```
  [{
    "self": "link",
    "id": "18900",
    "name": "AUDI",
    "releaseDate": "2015-12-11"
  },
  {
    "self": "link",
    "id": "18900",
    "name": "FORD",
    "releaseDate": "2015-12-11"
  }]
```

Sample Output:

```
  [{
    "self": "link",
    "id": "18900",
    "name": "audi",
    "releaseDate": "2015-12-11"
  }]
```

How do I write a simple line of code in a script to change the name fields to be lowercase values and to filter out objects where id and releaseDate are null?

Thank you.

Comment: None of `releaseDate` and `id` are `null` in your input sample. Please provide a meaningful example.

Comment: BTW, what code have you done so far, and what is your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your example does not seem to agree with your stated requirements, but the following will select the objects for which both .id and .releaseDate are non-null, and convert the ASCII alphabetic characters in the .name value to lowercase:

```
map(select(.id and .releaseDate) | .name |= ascii_downcase)
```

You can easily modify the selection criteria.

Answer (score -4):

you need java implements or any other language?

Comment: Please don't post questions as answers. In any case, the title says `jq`.